# polynomial problem ? need help

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

**I am  stuck in this question ** can you help me?

> let $p(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ be a plynomial with integer coefficients that $\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1}$ as a root. Compute $\{a,b,c,d\}$.

thank you for helping me?

Comment: What do you mean by $\sqrt{\sqrt{x}+1}$ is a root? Is this for all $x$? For some specific $x$?

Comment: Sorry , l commit atypo ; i make it right

Comment: $a,b,c,d$ are not fixed by what you've presented. We have one equation in 4 variables.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = \sqrt{\sqrt 3 + 1}$

Then:

$y^2 = \sqrt 3 + 1$

$(y^2-1)^2 - 3 = 0$

Expand to get a quartic and compare coefficients to the original equation.

Comment: thank you for help , i get both  a, c zeros    and both b , d  zeros   ,  is it right?

Comment: @prayersmith Shouldn't you be getting $\{0,-2,0,-2\}$?

Comment: @@Deepak    exactly  Thank you Sir for helping me